# iScroll Scrolling Past Bottom?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, mobile-website, iscroll4

<s>You can easily see the problem on the first page here: http://m.vancouverislandlife.com/</s>

Scroll down (slide up) and allow the content to leave the page, and it doesn't bounce back and is lost forever. However, on pages whose content *does* overflow the page and is therefore supposed to be scrollable, the scrolling works correctly (see Accomodations > b&b's and scroll down for an example of this).

I noticed that on my computer, the scrolling on the first page is always stuck at `-899px`. I can't find anybody else who's experienced this problem and no matter what I try, I just can't fix it! Help!

(It's not exactly urgent, however, as the target audience of iPhones and iPod Touches aren't affected by this since they have so little screen room.)

Okay, new problem. To solve the iScroll issue, I just created a custom script. However, it's not working correctly on the *actual device*. On desktop browsers, it works just fine. On mobile, it occasionally jumps back to the top and won't recognize some touches. This is probably because of the way I cancelled the default event and had to resort to a bit of a hack. How can I fix this? (Yup - simple problem for a +500 bounty. Not bad, huh?)

Here's the script, and the website is at the usual place:

```
function Scroller(content) {
    function range(variable, min, max) {
        if(variable < min) return min > max ? max : min;
        if(variable > max) return max;
        return variable;
    }

    function getFirstElementChild(element) {
        element = element.firstChild;

        while(element && element.nodeType !== 1) {
            element = element.nextSibling;
        }

        return element;
    }

    var isScrolling = false;
    var mouseY = 0;
    var cScroll = 0;
    var momentum = 0;
    if("createTouch" in document) {
        content.addEventListener('touchstart', function(evt) {
            isScrolling = true;
            mouseY = evt.pageY;
            evt.preventDefault();
        }, false);
        content.addEventListener('touchmove', function(evt) {
            if(isScrolling) {
                evt = evt.touches[0];

                var dY = evt.pageY - mouseY;
                mouseY = evt.pageY;
                cScroll += dY;
                momentum = range(momentum + dY * Scroller.ACCELERATION, -Scroller.MAX_MOMENTUM, Scroller.MAX_MOMENTUM);

                var firstElementChild = getFirstElementChild(content);

                content.style.WebkitTransform = 'translateY(' + range(cScroll, -(firstElementChild.scrollHeight - content.offsetHeight), 0).toString() + 'px)';
            }
        }, false);
        window.addEventListener('touchend', function(evt) {
            isScrolling = false;
        }, false);
    } else {
        content.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
            isScrolling = true;
            mouseY = evt.pageY;
        }, false);
        content.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
            if(isScrolling) {
                var dY = evt.pageY - mouseY;
                mouseY = evt.pageY;
                cScroll += dY;
                momentum = range(momentum + dY * Scroller.ACCELERATION, -Scroller.MAX_MOMENTUM, Scroller.MAX_MOMENTUM);

                var firstElementChild = getFirstElementChild(content);

                content.style.WebkitTransform = 'translateY(' + range(cScroll, -(firstElementChild.scrollHeight - content.offsetHeight), 0).toString() + 'px)';
            }
        }, false);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evt) {
            isScrolling = false;
        }, false);
    }

    function scrollToTop() {
        cScroll = 0;
        content.style.WebkitTransform = '';
    }

    function performAnimations() {
        if(!isScrolling) {
            var firstElementChild = getFirstElementChild(content);
            cScroll = range(cScroll + momentum, -(firstElementChild.scrollHeight - content.offsetHeight), 0);
            content.style.WebkitTransform = 'translateY(' + range(cScroll, -(firstElementChild.scrollHeight - content.offsetHeight), 0).toString() + 'px)';
            momentum *= Scroller.FRICTION;
        }
    }

    return {
        scrollToTop: scrollToTop,
        animationId: setInterval(performAnimations, 33)
    }
}

Scroller.MAX_MOMENTUM = 100;
Scroller.ACCELERATION = 1;
Scroller.FRICTION = 0.8;
```

Comment: What happens if you set `bounce:true`? You might be aware of it but `position:fixed` doesn't work in mobile safari (until ios5). But then in ios5, you won't need any plugin as it supports kinetic scrolling [natively](http://johanbrook.com/browsers/native-momentum-scrolling-ios-5/). If changing the plugin is an option, have you looked at [touchScroll](https://github.com/neave/touch-scroll) and [scrollability](https://github.com/joehewitt/scrollability/)?

Comment: @Mrchief: `bounce: true` makes no difference and I don't want the user to be able to scroll past the edges anyway. I am aware of the fact that `position: fixed` doesn't work in mobile Safari (but it's not so much unsupported as it is ineffective because mobile Safari uses a moving viewport instead of a fixed one), I'm not targeting iOS5 anyways, and yes, changing the plugin is an option so I will look at those, thanks.

Comment: I tried to setup this locally, but wasn't successful (maybe due to the ajax calls which I don't have the php for or maybe it was late in night). Is it possible for you to dump static html that I can play with (jsfiddle will screw up things)? Surprisingly, last year I was using something else for kinetic scrolling with good results, I couldn't find the same plugin now (and I have moved on from that client too). Anyway, I'll try again.

Comment: @Mrchief: Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/QDuwk/1/ The links won't work of course, but the scrolling is there. You can flick it up off the page and not be able to get it back.

Comment: @minitech was this ever solved? It's annoying that it scrolls outside of the content boundaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Andrew was on the right track with regards to setting the height of the `#wrapper` div. As he pointed out that,

```
that.maxScrollY = that.wrapperH - that.scrollerH;
```

Normally, this would work. But now that you've changed your `#content` to `position: fixed`, the wrapper element is no longer "wrapping" your content, thus `that.wrapperH` has a value of 0, things break.

***Disclaimer: I did not go through the entire script so I may be wrong here***

When manually setting a height to `#wrapper`, say `500px`, it becomes,

```
that.maxScrollY = 500 - that.scrollerH;
```

The folly here is that when there's a lot of content and the window is small, `that.scrollerH` is relatively close in value to 500, say `700px`. The difference of the two would be `200px`, so you can only scroll 200 pixels, thus giving the appearance that it is frozen. This boils down to how you set that `maxScrollY` value.

***Solution (for Chrome browser at least):***

Since `#wrapper` effectively contains no content, we cannot use it in the calculations. Now we are left with the only thing that we can reliably get these dimensions from, `#content`. In this particular case, it appears that using the content element's `scrollHeight` yield what we want. This is most likely the one that has the expected behavior,

```
that.maxScrollY = that.scrollerH - that.scroller.scrollHeight;
```

`scrollerH` is the `offsetHeight`, which is roughly the height of what you see in the window. `scroller.scrollHeight` is the height that's considered scrollable. When the content does not exceed the length of the page, they are roughly equivalent to one another. That means no scroll. When there are a lot of content, the difference of these two values is the amount of scroll you need.

There is still a minor bug, and this looks like it's already there. When you have a lot of content, the last few elements are covered up by the bar when scrolled to the bottom. To fix this, you can set an offset such as,

```
that.maxScrollY = that.scrollerH - that.scroller.scrollHeight - 75;
```

The number 75 arbitrary. It's probably best if it's the height of the bar itself with 2 or 3 pixels for a bit of padding. Good luck!

*Edit:*

I forgot to mention last night, but here are the two sample pages that I used in trying to debug this problem.

[Long page](http://www.akngo.com/stackoverflow/7026114/long.html)
[Short page](http://www.akngo.com/stackoverflow/7026114/short.html)

Comment: Hm... when I visit either test page, the scrolling doesn't work quite right... and in my test, modifying the iScroll script did make things better, but it was still possible to "lose" the page with some quick gestures. I ended up making a custom one. Thanks anyways, though. I'll decide who to award the bounty to in a while.

Comment: Okay, the question has now changed - please try to answer!

Comment: I'm giving you the bounty for the effort, and it will go to you anyways. Please try to help with the new question, though.

Comment: Hm, I've never done mobile device coding before. I'll take a stab at it either tonight or tomorrow night.

Answer (score 1):

Your wrapper div seems to have a height of 0. So all the calculations are negative, setting it's height to the window height will correct the scroll issue. When I manually set the wrappers height via firebug and chromes debug bar the scroll functions as it should.

You #content div seems to have its size change on resize, probably a better idea to have the #wrapper div have its size change and then have #content inherit the size.

**[Edit]**
You don't believe me so codez, From iscroll-lite.js

```
refresh: function () {
  var that = this,
      offset;
  that.wrapperW = that.wrapper.clientWidth;
  that.wrapperH = that.wrapper.clientHeight;
  that.scrollerW = that.scroller.offsetWidth;
  that.scrollerH = that.scroller.offsetHeight;
  that.maxScrollX = that.wrapperW - that.scrollerW;
  that.maxScrollY = that.wrapperH - that.scrollerH;
```

In your page that translates to,

```
that.wrapperH = 0;
that.maxScrollY = -that.scrollerH
```

When a scroll finishes, this code gets called.

```
var that = this,

resetX = that.x >= 0 ? 0 : that.x < that.maxScrollX ? that.maxScrollX : that.x,
resetY = that.y >= 0 || that.maxScrollY > 0 ? 0 : that.y < that.maxScrollY ? that.maxScrollY : that.y;
...
that.scrollTo(resetX, resetY, time || 0);
```

See that `that.maxScrollY > 0 ?` ? If maxScrollY is negative then scrolling up will *never* bounce back.

Comment: Setting the height prevents it from scrolling at all, even on pages that should scroll...

Comment: @minitech Are you positive? Look at the [documentation](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) It says the wrapper requires a height to be set. At the very least you need to set the height and there is something else wrong.

Comment: @minitech ps, setting it to 100% won't work, you need to set #wrappers height in `px`s

Comment: I'm positive. Even when setting the height in pixels, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a CSS issue. In your stylesheet (mobile.css line 22), try removing `position:fixed` from `#content`.

That should allow the document to scroll normally (vertical scrollbar on a computer, "slideable" on a mobile browser).

Elements with `position:fixed` exit the normal flow of the document, their positioning is relative to the browser window. This is probably why you're having issues with scrolling. Fixed positioning is generally for elements which should always remain in the same place, even when the page is scrolled (ie. a notification bar "pinned" at the top of a page).

Comment: I know - but that was a fix to a previous problem which apparently has no other way of getting around.

Comment: Try it - remove `position: fixed`, and change pages - the entire content disappears during the transition.

Comment: Try changing `position:fixed;` to `position:absolute;`, that should preserve your transitions.

Comment: Already tried that in the first problem. Surprisingly, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

No definite solution, but more a direction I'd go for:
#wrapper and #content's overflow:hidden paired #content's postion:fixed and  seem to be the cause of the issue.

If position: fixed is removed from #content, scrolling is possible but the "blank" divs are wrongly layered (tested in Firefox 5).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just making my own, small script to handle the scrolling:

```
// A custom scroller
function range(variable, min, max) {
    if(variable < min) return min > max ? max : min;
    if(variable > max) return max;
    return variable;
}

var isScrolling = false;
var mouseY = 0;
var cScroll = 0;
if("createTouch" in document) {
    // TODO: Add for mobile browsers
} else {
    content.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
        isScrolling = true;
        mouseY = evt.pageY;
    }, false);
    content.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
        if(isScrolling) {
            var dY = evt.pageY - mouseY;
            mouseY = evt.pageY;
            cScroll += dY;

            var firstElementChild = content.getElementsByTagName("*")[0];

            content.style.WebkitTransform = 'translateY(' + range(cScroll, -(firstElementChild.scrollHeight - content.offsetHeight), 0).toString() + 'px)';
        }
    }, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evt) {
        isScrolling = false;
    }, false);
}
```

and modifying a few other parts. It does save a lot of download time, I suppose, also.

I'm still going to accept answers and award the bounty in 5 days, though.

Comment: Very nice! It's interesting that you're calculating based off of the first child. A few things I'd recommend changing. You should use `firstElementChild.offsetHeight` as it appears to be what you want. If the first element has a lot of `overflow: hidden/scroll` content, your calculation will be off. Second is to use `content.children[0]` instead of `getElementsByTagName()`. `children` is an array of all HTML element, so it doesn't include text nodes. Third, since you're doing `-(A - B)`, I *personally* think it's better to do (B - A) because it's cleaner.

Comment: @Anh-Kiet Ngo: Thanks for the `offsetHeight` tip, don't know what I was thinking there... but about the `overflow` possible problem, I have a dedicated "inner" `<div>` and it's actually the only child. Thanks also for the `children` tip, I had changed it away from `getElementsByTagName()` to my own method but of course that looks much faster. And finally, I'll change it to `B - A`. It's an alpha version right now :) Since I've posted it I've added momentum like iScroll has and put it into its own object. Still to come is the cancellation of the default scrolling, though.

Comment: @Anh-Kiet Ngo: I've edited my question to change it and include my updated script. It's been recently changed from "almost working without hacks" to "almost working, but with hacks" so it should be easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Changed question warrants a new answer. I took a look at the code and I saw that you calculated the momentum on each step of the "move" function. This does not make sense because the momentum is used after the move has ended. What this meant was to capture the mouse position at the beginning, and then calculate the difference at the end. So I added two new variables,

```
var startTime;
var startY;
```

Inside the start event (mousedown/touchstart), I added,

```
startY = evt.pageY;
startTime = evt.timeStamp || Date.now();
```

Then I have the following for my end handler,

```
var duration = (evt.timeStamp || Date.now()) - startTime;
if (duration < 300) {
    var dY = evt.pageY - startY;
    momentum = range(momentum + dY * Scroller.ACCELERATION, -Scroller.MAX_MOMENTUM, Scroller.MAX_MOMENTUM);
} else {
    momentum = 0;
}
```

I also removed the momentum calculation from inside of mousemove/touchmove. Doing this removed the jumping around behavior that I was seeing on my iPhone. I am seeing other unwanted behaviors as well (the whole window "scrolls"), but I'm guessing that you've been working to get rid of those so I didn't attempt.

Good luck. Here's a [coded up page](http://www.akngo.com/stackoverflow/7026114/new-long.html) that I duplicated for my testing. I also took the liberty to refactor the code for this section to remove some duplicated code. It's under mobile3.js if you want to look at it.